# Using variable to recursively hash files in Python gives false hash

Tags: python, hash, md5

I am trying to print our the md5 hashes for the files within a directory recursively using Python, but I'm having problems with the variable in my open command producing false hashes. Here's my code:

```
import os
import hashlib

blocksize = 65536
md5_hash = hashlib.md5()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        os.chdir(root)
        with open(filename, 'rb') as cur_file:
            print filename
            while True:
                data = cur_file.read(blocksize)
                if not data:
                    break
                md5_hash.update(data)
        print md5_hash.hexdigest()
```

If I change the "filename" variable to a specific file, like this:

```
with open('nameoffile.txt', 'rb') as cur_file:
```

Then the correct hash is produced, leading me to believe that my for loops are faulty in some way. Am I on the right track with that? What can I do to fix the variable or for loops to get this to work properly?

Comment: You want the md5 for *individual* files? Because currently your code calculates the md5 of the concatenation of all the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never reset the hash object, i.e. you calculate the hash of the concatenation of all the files. Try moving the `md5_hash = hashlib.md5()` into the loop:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/path/to/folder'):
    for filename in files:
        md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
        os.chdir(root)
        with open(filename, 'rb') as cur_file:
            print filename
            while True:
                data = cur_file.read(blocksize)
                if not data:
                    break
            md5_hash.update(data)
        print md5_hash.hexdigest()
```

Also: why the chdir? `open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'rb')` should do fine without the additional syscall (and possible indeterminate state in case of an error).

Comment: This worked! Argh, so simple yet so effective. The os.chdir(root) is just habit (and a bit of lazy scripting) from old scripts. I haven't quite grasped os.path.join completely yet in my head, so I tend to go back to old habits to get things working quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
```

after you're done hashing a file, because you're currently updating the same one...

Comment: That's exactly what I had to do. Thanks!